# I can't delete folder on windows 7 and windows 10 even i have admin rights

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-folders

[Please check this error image and help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdxiq.png)

I can't delete empty folder in windows 7 and 10.

I tried few options to delete from dos and delete from safe mode. but its not working. i tried to rename it. which is also not working.

please help me to delete these kind of folders.

is there any software using which i can delete these kind of folders forcefully?

Comment: Looks like the files/folder no longer exists in the location the error indicates.  Are you sure the files actually exist?

Comment: Item not found errors are generally thrown because the item in question has been moved or deleted. For instance, a shortcut pointing to something that got moved or deleted. There are a number of possibilities, but I would generally start with a reboot, then with the `chkdsk` cmd to find/fix bad sectors. Wanted to give you somthing to start with.

Comment: In `cmd` you could try deleting the 8.3 name, which you can find by using `dir /x`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all people who help out to resolve my issue.

I have tired all suggestions and other suggestions on internet. but nothing work out.

So.
I thought about something different.
i have downloaded Ubantu and create bootable pendrive. and start computer with pendrive and select "Try Ubantu" and delete all files and folders which i couldn't delete using windows.

I also thought about deleting all partition drive in which i have problem folders and than create new partition drives. but i don't need it.